# Should the last column in a table typically be right aligned?

Tags: tables, data-tables, formatting

[This answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/45384/39046) says that left vs right alignment should be based on the data type in the column. For example, left align text and right align numbers.

I have heard that you should right align your last column though, even if it is a data type like text that is typically left aligned. Is this true?

Comment: Is it because right alignment of the last column is aesthetically pleasing? Because that’s ridiculous. Alignment should only be based on data type. Unless it is not meant to be functional.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Always right align things that needs comparison in terms of length. For example, numbers/price/rate which needs visual comparision of number of digits.

For texts, prefer left alignment.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion - the alignment depends on 2 things:

1. the type of data you want to show. Be careful, not all numbers need to be right-aligned.
2. the language used in your tables. For left-aligned languages (like English) use left alignment, for right-aligned languages (like Arabic) use right alignment.

So, the last column can be left aligned and it's ok